# implementing an interface with two different method signature and body

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, interface

I have two classes I want them to implements a particular Interface called LinearList, they have a lot of methods in common, but one of the method call add , it has two different arguments and the body of the method is different in both of the classes, so how can I add the method add to the interface

```
public void add(String item) {
  array.add(item);
}

public void add(int index, Object theElement) {
  if (index < 0 || index > size)
    // invalid list position
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException
      ("index = " + index + "  size = " + size);

  // valid index, make sure we have space
  if (size == element.length) {
    // no space, double capacity
    Object [] newArray = new Object[element.length*2];
    System.arraycopy(element,0,newArray,0,element.length);     
    element = newArray;
  }

  // shift elements right one position
  for (int i = size - 1; i >= index; i--)
    element[i + 1] = element[i];

    element[index] = theElement;
    System.out.println("added ok");
    size++;
  }
}


public interface LinearList {
  public int size();
  public void add(int index, Object theElement);
}
```

Comment: In that case both classes don't implement `LinearList` as the interface defines the methods. You either need to add both the `add` methods to the interface or change the `add` method on one of the classes.

Answer (score 1):

You add the two different methods to the interface:

```
void add(String item);
void add(int index, Object theElement);
```

When you implement this interface, you have to add both methods in your class.

Comment: You don't need `public` in an `interface`. All `interface` members are `public`.

Comment: This way, both the methods need to be implemented in both the classes. Wouldn't that be an overhead?!

Comment: Yeah, I completely forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

When two methods have the same name but different arguments then this is called [method overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading). Java interfaces support method overloading so you just declare them both:

```
void add(int index, Object theElement);
void add(String item);
```

This will force you to implement both, if you don't want to do that the only solution is by using two interfaces (and maybe a third common interface). Eg:

```
interface GenericAddable {
  void add(String item);
}

interface IndexedAddable {
  void add(int index, Object element);
}

interface LinearList {
  void method1();
  void method2();
}

class List1 implements LinearList, GenericAddable {
  ..
}

class List2 implements LinearList, IndexedAddable {
  ..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a parent interface for your specific interfaces:

```
    interface Addable {
    /* common methods go here */
    }

   interface LinearListAddable extends Addable {
   void add(int index, Object theElement);
   }

   interface IndexedAddable extends Addable {
   /* some other specific add method */
   }

  class Test implements IndexedAddable {
  /*  add method implemeted */
  }
```